# First Time Using XGBoost Regressor

Tags: python, machine-learning, xgboost

Been battling for a while to get this to work and to be able to find a solid guide for xgboost. Can't find anything on sklearn, So I'm trying to piece together bits from xgboost walk throughs.

```
def gradientBoost():
    xg_reg = xgb.XGBRegressor(objective="reg:linear", max_depth=5, n_estimators=100, random_state=42)
    xg_reg.fit(x_train, y_train)
    preds = xg_reg.predict(x_train)
    rmse = np.sqrt(metrics.mean_squared_error(y_train,preds))
    print("RMSE: %f" % rmse)
```

Using this code I get an error:

```
y_true and y_pred have a different number of outputs (18!=1)
```

I know you can't see the data I'm using, but if I'm training it on x_train,y_train how can the dimensions be different when I try get the accuracy of the prediction of the very data I used to train it?

Comment: Please post a sample of your `y_train` and `preds`, as well as the **full** error trace.

Comment: y_train is a (6475,18) array. preds is a (6475,) array. I'm starting to understand that I need to use the objective 'multi:softmax' but am having difficulty with the num_class parameter

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you there are 18 elements on `y_true` and 1 only in `y_pred` so the issue might come from your `y_pred`. You should try to print it and understand your error. I think `y_pred` is an array of array, of something like that, maybe `y_pred[0]` will work, but just print it and see what you did wrong, I can't help you more without that...

Comment: So after comparing to my previous random forest model which is set up exactly the same, the y_pred(preds variable) is an array(6475,18) which is the same shape as the input y_train. Using xgboost and the predict functions, it changes y_pred to an array(6475). I don't understand why the same function with the different regressors produces different results and produces a 1D array when it's been trained on a 2D array?

Comment: xgboost is independant from sklearn, so it's understandable that they don't work exactly the same, but for sure your error is due to the difference of outputs.

Comment: Is there a better function to use than predict()? One that would be the equivalent to predict() in sklearn?

Comment: Idk, but note that xgboost outputs changes with the "objective" parameter. See [this](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/03/complete-guide-parameter-tuning-xgboost-with-codes-python/), at chapter "Learning Task Parameters", 1.objective [default=reg:linear]